# Is there a ratio (root) test for complex valued sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

I am reading a book about complex analysis (Complex Analysis by Ian Stewart/David Tall). Can we use the ratio test (or the n-th root test) for complex valued sequences as well? If so, how can this test be applied for such sequences? Also, what tests can be used on complex valued sequences to find their limits (For example, how can you prove that the sequences: $z_n=i\sqrt{2}+(\frac{3-4i}{6})^n$ converges to $i\sqrt{2}$)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You consider the absolute value anyway in the root or ratio tests to obtain absolute convergence (or not), that works identically in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that
$$
i\sqrt{2}+\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^n\to i\sqrt{2},
$$
or that
$$
\left(\frac{3-4i}{6}\right)^n\to 0,
$$
it suffices to show that
$$
\left|\frac{3-4i}{6}\right|^n\to 0.
$$
But
$$
\left|\frac{3-4i}{6}\right|=\left|\frac{3^2+4^2}{36}\right|^{1/2}=\frac{5}{6}<1,
$$
and hence
$$
\left|\frac{3-4i}{6}\right|^n=\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n\to 0,
$$
due to ratio test!